# Keras: LSTM unit nums vs timesteps

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am using Keras LSTM (Tensorflow backend) to fit a time series model. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(LSTM_nums, input_shape=(timestep,data_dim)))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

I am wondering is there a constraint or rule of thumb (or best practice) for setting the LSTM_nums value with a given timestep? I.e. should there be a relationship between `LSTM_nums ~ timestep` ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The n_neurons (LSTM_nums) on the first input layer should match those of n_features or in your case data_dim.

Further reading: [LSTM Neural Network for Time Series Prediction](http://www.jakob-aungiers.com/articles/a/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct relationship between LSTM_nums and timesteps. LSTM_nums would be the number of hidden neurons (output dimensionality/vector) whereas timesteps is how far back the model could remember its state (unfold).